# Handwriting Recognition in Unity Application using Microsoft Cognitive Services

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to do Handwriting Recognition in a Unity Application using Microsoft Cognitive Services. I followed this link to code a script in C# - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts-sdk/csharp-hand-text-sdk#create-and-run-the-sample-app

However, Unity shows errors "The type or namespace name "Azure" could not be found". I'm new to Unity/C# dev. and cannot understand why this is happening.

Comment: Right click your solution and select "Restore NuGet Packages."

Comment: Still the same errors. There seem to be no errors in Visual studio since the IDE does not show any compiler errors, but Unity shows the above errors for Azure, TextRecognitionMode, ComputerVisionClient references

Comment: ok, I restarted everything and now Visual Studio also shows errors in line -  using Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision;  The type or namespace name "Azure" could not be found

Comment: I just cloned the repo at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-vision-csharp-sdk-quickstarts, updated all the NuGet packages, and now the build is succeeding. Try updating the NuGet packages?

Comment: Also, did you follow the QuickStarts? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-vision-csharp-sdk-quickstarts

Comment: The quick starts compiled successfully. However, the other project is still giving the same error after updating the packages. Could it be because this is a Unity project? Or something to do with .Net Core/Standard/Framework mismatch?

Comment: There must be some NuGet package problems in your other project. Do the packages in your other project match the ones in the Quickstart?

Comment: In project References, I can't see the Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision reference which is present in the quickstart. The nuget package manager shows the package as installed. I reinstalled and updated it, but nothing happens.

Comment: Try uninstalling/reinstalling the package and/or cleaning the solution.

Comment: Cleaned and uninstalled and reinstalled. Same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's because Unity overwrites the Visual Studio packages etc. This link describes the problem and how to add dlls to Unity instead of installing packages in Visual Studio - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/unity-scripting-upgrade?view=vs-2019